# Finding multiple objects in an array and adding to count value for that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I have been toying with the best way to go about doing this and have found some options but not one that preserves the format I am trying to keep for the array/object.

The overview is I have an array that gets random objects pushed into it and there can be duplicates of the same object, but I want to change it so there is only 1 of each object and instead, having a count property for each object.

An example of what I am working with and what I am aiming to have.

```
arr = [
  { Name: Item1, Value: 20 },
  { Name: Item2, Value: 20 },
  { Name: Item1, Value: 20 }
];

result = [
  { Name: Item1, Value: 20, Count: 2 },
  { Name: Item2, Value: 20, Count: 1 }
];
```

As a side note, I am wondering if it better to do this after the array is filled or if it is better to do this while pushing the objects into the array?

Comment: do you want to group by `Name` and `Value`, or only by `Name`?

Comment: Only by name, the values for each of the objects in the array will all be the same anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the value of each item is the same, you can do a simple forEach loop. For each element, check to see if the object exists in 'result'. If so, increment the count, otherwise add it to the result array.

```
let result = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  let resObj = result.find(resObj => resObj.Name === item.Name);
  resObj ? resObj.Count++ : result.push({'Name':item.Name, 'Value': item.Value, 'Count': 1});
});

console.log(result);
```

In this case, you don't want to use arr.map, since we're not updating the original array.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was thinking for how to do it, trying to get a good grasp on manipulating an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If items are continuously being added, you can maintain an "index" (by `Name`) of objects you've already added to the array so that whenever a new object is added, you can update the count if it's already present or push it to the array if it's not:

```js
var arr = [];
var index = {};

function addItem(o) {
  if (o.Name in index) {
    index[o.Name].Count += 1;
  } else {
    index[o.Name] = o;
    o.Count = 1;
    arr.push(o);
  }
}

addItem({
  Name: 'Item1',
  Value: 20
});
addItem({
  Name: 'Item2',
  Value: 20
});
addItem({
  Name: 'Item1',
  Value: 20
});

console.log(arr);
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to recompute counts from scratch (which is an *O(n)* operation) every time you want to get the `result` array.

Comment: This doesn't match OPs expected output - he's adding a `Count` property, not incrementing `Value`

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was thinking of how to do this beforehand, and have the Count already apart of the object.

I never used an index before and had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and maintain 1 temporary object with "Name" as a key, If same name is found increment "count" by 1

```js
let array = [{ Name: 'Item1', Value: 20 }, { Name: 'Item2', Value: 20 }, { Name: 'Item1', Value: 20 }]
    
let tempResult = {}
for (let d of array) {
  tempResult[d.Name] = { 
     count: 1, 
     ...d, 
     ...(tempResult[d.Name] &&  { count: tempResult[d.Name].count + 1 }) 
  }
}

let result = Object.values(tempResult)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and count same items.

```js
var array = [{ Name: 'Item1', Value: 20 }, { Name: 'Item2', Value: 20 }, { Name: 'Item1', Value: 20 }],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, { Name, Value }) => {
        r[Name] = r[Name] || { Name, Value, Count: 0 };
        r[Name].Count++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```